# Using crontab to print hello

Tags: unix, cron

I'm trying to echo "Hello World" on my Unix system. I'm trying to do this by running: `sudo crontab -u myusername -e 2 14 18 1 * echo "Hello World"` however I'm receiving the following usage error:

```
crontab: usage error: no arguments permitted after this option
usage: crontab [-u user] file
       crontab [-u user] { -e | -l | -r }
```

Why is this?

Comment: when you get error messages like this, learn to use `man crontab` or `info crontab` to read the available documentation **for your system**. The modern crontab doc files I've looked at are well written and include examples near the bottom. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
-e: Edit the current crontab using the editor specified by the VISUAL
or EDITOR environment variables.
```

So you can't put `2 14 18 1 * echo "Hello World"` as arguments. You can call `sudo crontab -u myusername -e` and then put `2 14 18 1 * echo "Hello World"` as content when the editor shows up.

Comment: Ah. How would I make multiple crontabs then?

Comment: Separate them by newlines?